safari memory timeline unable to display complete memory type distribution
There are four categories(JavaScript、Images、Layers、Page) of memory recorded in the official document(https://webkit.org/blog/6425/memory-debugging-with-web-inspector/)

but my Mac only have JavaScript and Page.

how can I get four types of memory distribution.
safari: 17.0 (19616.1.27.211.1)
mac: Apple M1 Pro 14.0 (23A344)
